# Why isn't scanf working when I try entering strings in a char pointer array?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *msg[10];

    scanf("%s", msg[0]);        
    scanf("%s", msg[1]);       
    scanf("%s", msg[2]);      
    scanf("%s", msg[3]);    
}
```

When I try to run this code, it gives errors. Am I doing something wrong? I'm still a beginner in C language.

Comment: `scanf` does not allocate memory.

Comment: You have an array of ten *uninitialized* pointers. Where do they point? Who knows. All we know is that you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *msg[10];
```

Here `msg` is **array of 10 char pointer** and they are not initialized. If you  want to store something into them, first allocate the memory dynamically.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  msg[i] = malloc(MAX_NO_OF_BYTES); /* MAX_NO_OF_BYTES is the no of bytes you want to allocate */
  scanf("%s",msg[i]); /* store the data into dynamically allocated memory */
}
```

print it & do the operation as you wanted

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         printf("%s\n",msg[i]);
          /** operation with array of char pointer **/
 }
```

Once work is done, free the dynamically allocated memory using `free()` for each char pointer as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      free(msg[i]);
 }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Aw man, thanks! I'm new here, and I don't really know how to pick this as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `char *msg[10]` is a array of 10 char pointers for which you need to explicitly allocate memory or use a static array instead.

**Option-1:**

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
  msg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100)
}
```

**Option-2**

```
char msg[10][100]
```